How to disable the 'AI Overview' from Google Search?
How do I disable the unwanted "AI summary" from Google Search. It's basically just noise to me.
Ex: Search “Switzerland treaties”

AI Overview
Switzerland has a number of treaties, including:
Double taxation agreements
....

I've looked at Google search settings but see nothing to remove this.

I agree it is unwanted and annoying. But energy-intensive? That's a bit of a stretch for results that pop up automatically and instantly with all the other search results. Everything computer/web-based uses energy, trying to blame AI for making searches use more energy is a bit of a stretch. But annoying and bordering on useless? Absolutely.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Well, LLMs are known to be extremely energy hungry, but I agree it is unsure that this is still the case at the search/exploitation phase, rather than just at the training phase.  I guess the combination of useless and wasteful gets to me, but I'll remove it from the Q where it distracts from the main point:  removal.

As from cnet.com July 1, 2024
Earlier this year, there seemed to be a way to turn off AI Overviews in search results, but now it's hardwired in results.
So, is there any other way to get rid of AI Overviews?
Google may not give us an obvious way to turn off AI Overviews in Google search, but there are some workarounds.
The first workaround, whether you're on mobile or a computer, is to use the Web tab that appears at the top of Google search results. If you don't see it -- it should be in there with the "All," "News" and "Images" tabs -- scroll left or right until you do. You'll still initially see an AI summary at the top, but this allows you to quickly go to a more traditional search, filled with only links. If you're on a computer, there's a way you can make the web tab the default option when you use Google Search online.
A second workaround is to use another web browser other than Chrome. We didn't receive AI Overviews for queries in Safari and Firefox. Unfortunately, this only works on your computer, not on mobile.

Your claimed workaround of using another browser is invalid.  I get the AI Overview just fine with Firefox on Macos.  It's hard to see in any case why Google would limit its "service" to only being available on particular browser.

@JLPeyret, monopolistic practices? There's a reason this addon exists
